# Grouped Select2 and JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, jbuilder

The Select2 Jquery tools expects json data back like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    { 
      "text": "Group 1", 
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Option 1.1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Option 1.2"
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "text": "Group 2", 
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "Option 2.1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "text": "Option 2.2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a jbuilder script like this:

```
json.results do
  json.text "Assets"
  json.children do
    json.array!(@assets) do |asset|
      json.id asset.tracker_id
      json.text asset.name
    end
  end
end
```

which outputs:

```
{
  "results":
     {
        "text":"Assets",
        "children"...
```

Note the missing [] around the results - I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this with jBuilder (if possible at all).  Can I do this with jBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

I somehow broke down the logic myself:

```
json.results [1] do |results|
  json.text "Assets"
  json.children do
    json.array!(@assets) do |asset|
      json.id asset.tracker_id
      json.text asset.name
    end
  end
end
```

Adding the [1] and do loop worked like a charm.